# ApplicationSignificantTimeChange firing reason

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

My application uses ApplicationSignificantTimeChange method for detecting time changes from device settings. But this method is called for arrival of midnight or an update of the time by a carrier or the change to daylight savings time. Is it possible to distinguish the reason for the notification initiation ?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no way to distinguish between those, but depending on what you want to accomplish exactly - there's probably a better way to do it.

For example, if you're looking for the the next moment of the following day, you can register for the `NSCalendarDayChangedNotification` on iOS 7

Comment: My application supports iOS 5+. Can you suggest some common technique ?

Comment: Here are a couple of libraries that can get you when the next midnight date is, you could schedule a local notification, if you'd like a notification or just use the date, if that's what you need.
https://github.com/jivadevoe/RandomLib/blob/master/NSDate%2BUtils.h
https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions/blob/master/NSDate-Utilities.h

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not - there is no dictionary or information passed with this call. You will have to look to other solutions to implement what you are trying to achieve.